# How to install python packages with virtualenv without installing them globally?

Tags: python, sudo, virtualenv

I have installed `virtualenv` with `sudo apt-get install virtualenv`. It stands [in this tutorial](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/) that you need to use your `env/bin/` folder's own `pip` or `pip3` command to install modules in the virtual environment, and it is **explicitly stated that you don't use** `sudo` to do this.

Unfortunately that doesn't work for me, I get a `PermissionError` when I try doing that. But using sudo before `pip3` will install the module globally, so I won't get to take advantage of having a virtual environment at all.

E.g. when in my env/bin/ folder, I run `pip3 install pytest`:

```
Collecting pytest
  Downloading pytest-3.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (172kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 174kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting py>=1.4.29 (from pytest)
  Downloading py-1.4.33-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 2.1MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pytest)
Installing collected packages: py, pytest
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/py-1.4.33.dist-info'
```

How do I get started using `virtualenv` on Ubuntu 16.04 in less painful way?

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment?

Comment: I have tried running env/bin/activate in any way I could think of: with `./activate`, or `sudo activate`. Nothing worked.

Comment: You are supposed to `source` it. The command to do that is mentioned in the link you gave: `source env/bin/activate`.

Comment: While that's true and I thank for pointing that out, the blog post only mentions the activation with `source` in the section coming after demonstrating the basic usage of `virtualenv`.  That's where I got tripped off.

Comment: After activating the virtual environment, are you able to install `pytest`?

Answer (score 2):

After you create the virtual environment, you need to activate it:

```
$ virtualenv myenv
$ source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv) $ pip install pytest
```

or for Python 3:

```
$ virtualenv -p `which python3` myenv
$ source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv) $ pip3 install pytest
```

When you are finished using the environment, you can deactivate it like so:

```
$ deactivate
```